# I started trying to install MariaDB MySQL. Now I have a mess, looks like I can't install packages now

Tags: server, apt, package-management, mysql

First of all, I don't know very much about Ubuntu. It's Ubuntu 16.04 Server (64 bits).

I needed to install a MySQL database, using `apt-get install mariadb-server`. It worked, it's been installed but it asked me no password or anything. Unable to set a password, I just uninstalled it using the `apt-get remove`.

Then I wanted to try using `apt-get install mysql-server`, giving me an error. Well, I searched the web for solutions, and I've used commands I don't even know what do they do. And now, I have this mess where I can't install packages.

It seems that both are already installed, but when I try to do something with them:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

And I can't even install gedit to try and edit a file that's supposed to have a solution to this problem.

Argh... What the heck can I do? I'm very lost right now, and I'm afraid that if I can't solve this, I'll have to format and reinstall everything.

[image: Ubuntu command terminal image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinstall. If you don't have any valuable data in your databases, you can try this :

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mariadb-server
```